# How to rename the built-in Administrators group in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory

As you probably know, if you promote a new domain in a new forest on a non-English Windows Server OS, all built-in groups are localized. I'm trying to rename an Active Directory Domain's built-in groups back to English, in a test environment.

The issue is that the built-in groups -- e.g. the *Administrators* group -- have a couple of *systemFlags* such as *DOMAIN_DISALLOW_RENAME*, preventing me from renaming the group.

I tried running ldp.exe as SYSTEM on the domain controller and deleting the systemFlags attribute, but it fails due to permissions.

```
***Call Modify...
ldap_modify_s(ld, 'CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com',[1] attrs);
Error: Modify: Constraint Violation. <19>
Server error: 000020B1: AtrErr: DSID-030F158A, #1:
    0: 000020B1: DSID-030F158A, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 90177 (systemFlags)

Error 0x20B1 The attribute cannot be modified because it is owned by the system.
```

I found a [thread here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23921971/How-to-rename-builtin-administrators-group.html) where a person achieved this, but he skipped the details and I am not able to get this right.

> Well, finally i found a way to rename it using ldp.exe after binding to server by changing schema attribute
> Thanks

So, how would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried this approach? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-rename-an-active-directory-group/ It uses a Move instead of a Rename, so it might get past the DOMAIN_DISALLOW_RENAME flag.

Comment: It's just one of the flags. Those groups cannot be renamed, moved or deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps worked for me.

> 1. Launch *LDP.exe* and bind to the DS server you want to modify. Make sure
>    you are schema admin, and admin over the partition you are modifying
> 2. After connecting and binding, navigate to the browse menu and select the "Modify" option.
> 3. Leave the DN blank, type *schemaUpgradeInProgress* into the Attribute field and in the values field type 1.
> 4. Click the *Add* operation and then click the *Enter* button. This will add this command to the entry list.
> 5. Click the *Run* button. If you are successful you should see a successful modify message.
> 6. Go to *View -> Tree*. Connect to the appropriate base DN.
> 7. Find the object, right click and select *Modify*.
> 8. In the *Attribute* field, type "systemflags"; in the *Values* field, leave it blank; in the operation radio options, select *Delete*.
> 9. Then click *Enter*, then click *Run* to remove the system flags values.
> 10. Perform the modification of the object.
> 11. Set the *systemflags* value back to the original value, to make it owned by the system again
> 12. Once finished, run LDP again with the above steps, changing the *schemaUpgradeInProgress* value to 0 (to prevent unwanted schema/system
>     changes).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/janelewis/how-to-modify-a-system-owned-object